# Already awarded bounty refunded on question migration?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties, specific-question, migrated-questions

In March 2011 I offered a 500 bounty on one of my StackOverflow questions ([10K link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094400/performance-of-non-clustered-indexes-on-heaps-vs-clustered-indexes?noredirect=1)) and awarded it to Filip de Vos.

This question was later migrated to Database Administrators and has the following messages on it.

> ### migrated to dba.stackexchange.com by Will♦ Dec 28 '11 at 12:25
>
> This
>   question belongs on our site for database professionals who wish to
>   improve their database skills and learn from others in the community.

.

> ### deleted Dec 31 '11 at 1:01

I appear to have been [refunded the points on Dec 31](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2012-03-02%2008:35:22Z&page=3)  on whereas Filip [lost them on Dec 28](https://stackoverflow.com/users/619960/filip-de-vos?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=1).

Is this a bug? Definitely doesn't seem fair or correct to me. The question still shows up in both our bounty tabs despite the migration. I would have hoped that the previously awarded bounty reputation points could still be honoured in this situation.

Comment: The bounty was removed from Filip De Vos's rep on the 28/12/11; http://stackoverflow.com/users/619960/filip-de-vos?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=1

Comment: @Matt - Ah. That seems harsh as he answered the question in good faith. The question still shows up on my offered bounties and his earned bounties so still think this is a bug. If not I guess I should find another of his answers to award it on.

Comment: I agree the removal of the bounty is half complete in this instance at best ;)... and yes, it's a shame he lost the bounty... a considerable amount of work went into that answer!

Comment: I'm not sure if its a bug or not, but I feel bad.  Not about the migration; the question was definitely a good fit for DBA, and they deserve good quality questions/answers (like this one) that are NPR migrated to their site.  I've reversed everything so Filip has his bounty.  I'm keeping it closed with a note to point to the migrated answer.

Comment: @Won't - Thanks for doing that. I'll leave this question open in case anyone wants to answer as to whether or not this is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reputation awarded for the bounty is lost when the question is migrated, because the *answer* it was awarded to is deleted at that time.

When the *question* is deleted, the amount of the bounty offered on it is refunded.

Since these deletions rarely happen simultaneously (it would be confusing if they did!), there'll always be some time discrepancy between them.

Good reason not to offer bounties on questions that should be migrated, and not to migrate questions with bounties.